# Can't access register in FOS - too many redirects

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, registration

I installed FOS User Bundle into my Symfony project. I was following the steps in Symfony documentation, then I overridden two templates - layout.html.twig and Security/login_content.html.twig. But now I found out that /register page doesn't work, it returns error saying ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, /login works fine. I did the same thing a few weeks ago on different project and /register page is working fine there. So I had to mess up something, but I can't figure out what. The overidden templates are idenctical on both projects, same as security.yml and fos parts in config.yml. It won't even get to the registerAction() in RegistrationController.php in FOS directory in vendor, so there must be some problem with routing, it can't get to the proper action. Cache is cleared. Any idea?

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: /_wdt/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /_profiler/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

routing.yml

```
app:
resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

config.yml

```
# FOS User Bundle
fos_user:
db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
firewall_name: main
user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
from_email:
    address: admin@test.com
    sender_name: admins
```

Comment: change ^/register to ^/register$

Comment: It didn't help, but there must be something with it, it keeps redirecting from register to register/ to register to register/ and so on. Can't figure out how such a thing coul've messed up when I didn't do any major changes in terms of routing and configuration. I tried to revert the yml files back to how they look in the symfony fos user bundle documentation but no success.

Comment: Solved. This is what caused the issue. 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html